# Como usar refresh_token con OAuth2RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, oauth2, resttemplate

Desde un servicio hecho con spring-boot (servicio A), estoy intentando acceder a otro securizado (servicio B) con OAuth2 y JWT. Al iniciar el servicio A, obtengo el token de acceso (provisto por el servicio de autorización - Servicio C -) y logro conectarme con éxito al servicio B, pero una vez vencido mi token de acceso no logro llegar al servicio B, retornandome una Excepción:

***Authentication is required to obtain an access token (anonymous not allowed)***

Entiendo que en este momento debería pedir un nuevo access_token, con el refresh_token (del token vencido). Pero OAuth2RestTemplate no lo hace y me devuelve la Excepción antes mencionada.

Esta es la configuracion de mi OAuth2RestTemplate:

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class OAuth2RestTemplateConfig {

    @Value("${oauth2.uri.token}")
    private String tokenUrl;

    @Value("${oauth2.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${oauth2.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${oauth2.client-id}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${oauth2.client-secret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Bean(name = "cloudOAuth2ResourceDetails")
    protected OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource() {

        ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resource = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
        resource.setAccessTokenUri(tokenUrl);
        resource.setClientId(clientId);
        resource.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
        resource.setGrantType("password");
        resource.setScope(Arrays.asList("write", "read"));
        resource.setUsername(username);
        resource.setPassword(password);

        return resource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "cloudRestTemplate")
    public OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate() {

        AccessTokenRequest atr = new DefaultAccessTokenRequest();
        OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource(), new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(atr));
        restTemplate.getAccessToken();

        return restTemplate;
    }

}
```

Al pegarle por Postman al servicio de autorización (Servicio C), si me devuelve el nuevo token:

**Login con REFRESH_TOKEN**
[image: Login con REFRESH_TOKEN]

**Login con CREDENCIALES**
[image: Login con CREDENCIALES]

Answer (score 1):

Debuggeando el código de *OAuth2RestTemplate*, entra por el método *acquireAccessToken* para ir a *accessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken*

```
OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = null;
accessToken = accessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken(resource, accessTokenRequest);
if (accessToken == null || accessToken.getValue() == null) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(
            "Access token provider returned a null access token, which is illegal according to the contract.");
}
```

Y dentro del cual, pasa por los dos if anidados siguientes hasta lanzar la Excepción

```
if (auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) {
    if (!resource.isClientOnly()) {
        throw new InsufficientAuthenticationException(
                "Authentication is required to obtain an access token (anonymous not allowed)");
    }
}
```

Al parecer entra por la 1er implementación del *accessTokenProvider* (**AccessTokenProviderChain**), y es dentro de esta, donde esta el código anterior que me lanza la Excepción.

Con lo cual modifiqué *OAuth2RestTemplateConfig* para definirle el *accessTokenProvider* al bean "*cloudRestTemplate*":

```
@Bean(name = "cloudRestTemplate")
public OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate() {

    AccessTokenRequest atr = new DefaultAccessTokenRequest();
    OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource(), new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(atr));
    restTemplate.setAccessTokenProvider(new ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider());
    restTemplate.getAccessToken();

    return restTemplate;
}
```

Con esto al momento de hacer una llamada REST a mi API securizada, con un access_token vencido, va a buscar un nuevo token para poder acceder a dicha API.

Si bien el flujo funciona como quería, hay un detalle, y es que ***no voy a buscar un nuevo token con mi refresh_token***, sino que con mis credenciales.